# How can I find out and print the sum of non-matching records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here, I have these records:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 50 |
| 1 | 32 | 50 |
| 2 | 20 | 60 |
| 2 | 20 | 65 |
| 3 | 10 | 70 |

And the aim was to find the sum of matching ID's Value1s and for the Value2, find the sum of only non-matching records and others would stay as they were before.
Like here:

| ID | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 62 | 50 |
| 2 | 40 | 125 |
| 3 | 10 | 70 |

Comment: Will rows be unique or pairs or can there be more than two rows per Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like some odd logic, if I am honest. You could, however, use a CTE with some row numbering, followed by some conditional aggregation:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           Value1,
           Value2,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Value2 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --Which row is arbitrary as it doesn't matter
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT ID,
       SUM(Value1) AS Value1,
       SUM(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN Value2 END) AS Value2
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

…

```
declare @t table(id int,val1 int,val2 int);

insert into @t(id,val1,val2)
values(1,30,50),(1,32,50),(2,20,60),(2,20,65),(3,10,70);

select id, sum(val1) as val1, sum(distinct val2) as val2
from @t
group by id;
```